# python: if condition, it is very simple calculation, but it does not work

Tags: python, django

I wrote very simple calculation function as below;

```
direction == B
number == 2 

        def price_cal():
            if direction == 'A' and (number == 1):
                return 1

            elif direction == 'A' and (1 < number <= 9):
                return 2

            elif direction == 'A' and (9 < number <= 13):
                return 3

            elif direction == 'B' and (number == 1):
                return 4 

            elif direction == 'B' and (1 < number <= 9):
                return 5

            else:
                return 6

        price_cal()
```

If I run the function above with those inputs, then return has to be '5' right? but I got '6' (return 6)

When I run this function, only I get right answers from the first

```
 if direction == 'A' and number == 1:
                return 1
```

the rest of them, I get only answers from the last function

```
else:
     return 6
```

I don't know why this happen... please correct this simple function, much appreciated

ps; someone asked me to put some input... I think he does not understand this simple function anyway I put some above now.

Comment: what inputs are you providing in this... ?? also update the arguments which you are passing...

Comment: input > select. client can select from two options 'A' or 'B' and for 'no_of_passenger'; select from 1 to 13

Comment: looks like it works only 'if ....' and 'else...'   'elif ..' does not work

Comment: suburbs = { 'epping':  60, 'city' :50, ...... }  dictionary type, keys are 'name of suburb' and values are price. it works fine. something happen in 'if  conditon'.

Comment: working fine for me... checkout this link... https://replit.com/join/fnhfcegffy-shivendraprata3

Comment: for example, I select 'A' and 3, then this resutls has to come out but it does not. it comes out ````else:
                return int(suburbs.get(suburb)) + (int(no_of_passenger) * 10) + 20````

Comment: yes, I checked that. I don't know why it does not work properly. it apply to only first one and last one, if:  and else:

Comment: put a simple print in each section might help you... and try to debug...

Comment: Please edit the question so it demonstrates the problem and we can run the code the as you are doing. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: blueteeth> I edited simple one to maek people understood easily. is that okay now?

Comment: Do I have to make an exmaple for inputs ? okay then check it now

Comment: plz revise 「direction == B」 to 「direction = 'B'」
and 「number == 2」 to 「number = 2」… or you just use 「True」 or 「False」 to compare in if else conditions

Comment: I know... something happen at views.py... I could not find any bug (I did debugging but no bug)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer for my question

here are the codes it works fine below;

```
def price_detail(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        flight_date = request.POST.get('flight_date')
        direction = request.POST.get('direction')
        suburb = request.POST.get('suburb')
        no_of_passenger = request.POST.get('no_of_passenger')
        sub = int(suburbs.get(suburb))
        no_p = int(no_of_passenger)

        def price_cal1():
            if direction == 'Drop off to airport' and no_p == 1:
                return sub + (no_p * 10)
            elif direction == 'Drop off to airport' and 1 < no_p <= 9:
                return sub + (no_p * 10) - 10
            elif direction == 'Drop off to airport' and 9 < no_p <= 13:
                return sub + (no_p * 10) + 10
            elif direction == 'Pickup from airport' and no_p == 1:
                return sub + (no_p * 10) + 10
            elif direction == 'Pickup from airport' and 1 < no_p <= 9:
                return sub + (no_p * 10)
            else:
                return sub + (no_p * 10) + 20

        price_cal1()
        price = str(price_cal1())
```

Sorry... I found what the problem was. On html (webpage) {key and value} was not exactly same as objects in views.py... it was capital in html, just one letter but it was small letter in views. simeple mistake!

Answer (score 0):

I refactor your code to make it more readable, maybe now you realize your mistake:

```
def price_cal():
    no_p = int(no_of_passenger)
    sub  = int(suburbs.get(suburb))
    if direction == 'A' :
        if no_p == 1 :
            return sub + (no_p * 10)
        if 1 < no_p <= 9:
            return sub + (no_p * 10) - 10
        if 9 < no_p <= 13:
            return sub + (no_p * 10) + 20

    if direction == 'B':
        if no_p == 1 :
            return sub + (no_p * 10) + 10
        if 1 < no_p <= 9:
            return sub + (no_p * 10)

    return sub + (no_p * 10) + 20
```

post some input sample values for `direction` `no_p` and `sub` with the respective expected output, to offer you further help

Comment: no it does not work either... same results.

Comment: I just refactor, the logic is the same, post some samples like
| direction | no_p | sub | expected ouput |
|     'A'        |    1    |  10  |           20              |

I can't undestend your logic without context

Answer (score 0):

just want to let you know that when you use `and` it checks for both being true, and `or` checks for at least one being true. So here it might execute

`if direction == 'Drop off to airport' or no_p == 1: return sub + (no_p * 10)`

and

`elif direction == 'Pickup from airport' or no_p == 1: return sub + (no_p * 10) + 10`
no matter the input, because I assume direction is always exactly "Drop off to airport" or "Pickup from airport". if the `and` wasn't working why don't you check which of the conditions was not being checked properly?+ the direction string might not have the capital letter in the input or no_p might be a string(instead of integer type)

*disclaimer I am a beginner myself